# iTunes Wi-Fi sync remotely through VPN or any other method?

Tags: itunes, wifi, vpn

My PC is connected to my school's ethernet while my phone is connected to the Wi-Fi here, this means I can't do Wi-Fi syncing unless I physically use a cable, which is not the best experience as I use AltStore which requires resigning every 7 days.

Would it be possible to use a VPN or some other method to "trick" iTunes into being in the same network as my iPhone?

---

I found this googling: https://github.com/rileytestut/AltStore/issues/622#issuecomment-910115862

The user said that he was able to use a VPN with "arpproxying support". I haven't been able to find any details around that however.

I also saw an older answer on here to rebroadcast Bonjour which apparently is quite outdated.

Comment: Did you try to set your iPhone as modem and connect the PC to the iPhone wifi network ?